# How can I use regex for "contains this word"

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I'm trying to setup tracking in Google Analytics.

The goal URL is:

```
www.example.com/jdsfdf?sdfffs#/thankYou
```

Every time Google Analytics sees `#/thankYou` in the URL, I want it to attribute that as a conversion.

How can I use regex to say `if the URL contains #/thankYou, then it's a conversion`?

Comment: The regex for matching a string that ends with #/thankYou looks like: .*#\/thankYou$ assuming you need to escape the slash and that you want to match any characters at the start and want an end of line character at the end. I'm not sure if this will work for Google Analytics, but it might be a good starting point for you.

Comment: the regex sould be as simple as the (escaped) string you're looking for.

Comment: See https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034324?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a regex for an exact string match, but if you *must*:

```
/#\/thankYou/
```

or as [@Sundar points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980820/how-can-i-use-regex-for-contains-this-word/17980859?noredirect=1#comment26287391_17980859), you may not need to escape anything:

```
#/thankYou
```

Comment: I don't know if Google Analytics asks the regex to be surrounded by // characters (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034324?hl=en does not mention it), but if it does not, we don't even need to escape the /, it's just the exact literal string #/thankYou

Answer (score 0):

This regex will work for you (apparently no escaping is needed on the forward slash):

```
#/thankYou$
```

The dollar sign indicates that you require this string to appear a end of the URL. If you don't require that the thankYou come at the end, then remove the dollar sign.